# RecyclerAdapter is creating multiple view back to back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview to display images in cardview. When I load images from the url. It loads well from first time but when It loads for second time it is not displayed properly.

[image: This is how it is loaded second time]

How to fix it? Here is the code

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    dataList = FlickrDBOperation.dataArray
    if (dataList!!.isEmpty())
        return 0

    Log.e("count",dataList!!.size.toString())
    return dataList!!.size

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {

    var itemView: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.imagelist_row,parent,false)
    var viewHolder: FlickrAdapter.Holder = FlickrAdapter.Holder(itemView)


    return viewHolder

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {

    holder.image_name.text = dataList!!.get(position).name
    Picasso.with(context).load(dataList!!.get(position).preUrl).into(holder.row_image)

}


class Holder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val row_image: ImageView
    val image_name: TextView
    init {
        row_image  = itemView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.row_image)
        image_name = itemView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_name)
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the `dataArray` from dataList change from time to time? Cause `getItemCount()` is called a lot and maybe the bug gets in there somehow.

Comment: No it is filled once only when fragment is created